# EF Core 5 – "into" keyword not supported?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This query works fine with EF Core 5:

```cs
var query = from test1 in context.Test1
            join test2 in context.Test2 on test1.Id equals test2.Test1Id
            select new
            {
                test1,
                test2
            };
var result = query.ToList();
```

However, when I only add an `into` keyword:

```cs
var query = from test1 in context.Test1
            join test2 in context.Test2 on test1.Id equals test2.Test1Id into xxx
            select new
            {
                test1,
                test2 = xxx
            };
var result = query.ToList();
```

it throws:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ
> expression 'DbSet()
> .GroupJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: test1 => (Nullable)test1.Id,
> innerKeySelector: test2 => test2.Test1Id,
> resultSelector: (test1, xxx) => new {
> test1 = test1,
> test2 = xxx
> })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList',
> or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038
> for more information.

(The real query is of course more complicated and the `into` clause makes more sense.)

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GroupJoin` support in EF Core is still quite limited, but you can omit such limitation:

```cs
var query = from test1 in context.Test1
            select new
            {
                test1,
                test2 = context.Test2.Where(test2 => test1.Id == test2.Id).ToList()
            };
var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping in EF might be a pain. Developers might not be aware that not every grouping that is written in C# can be translated to SQL.

As a rule of thumb remember that grouping works only if you use some sort of aggregates. Then the query can be translated into SQL.

All other examples is just an expandable list like a Master/Detail view.

In SQL you can get a result like

- col1, col2, col3
- col1, col2, col3
- col1, col2, col3

but not

- col1, col2

  - item1_col1, item1_col2
  - item2_col1, item2_col2
  - item3_col1, item3_col2
- col1, col2

  - item4_col1, item4_col2
  - item5_col1, item5_col2
- col1, col2

  - item6_col1, item6_col2
  - item7_col1, item7_col2